# Как собирать раз в день цены с сайтов?

Tags: c#, asp.net, парсер

Хочу написать небольшой проект, который собирает данные стоимости медицинских анализов с сайтов разных клиник.

Есть ли реализация такой штуки? Например, на сервере стоит, возможно, служба или приложение, которое раз в день опрашивает сайты и записывает данные в базу. Клиент же получает данные из этой базы.

Как обычно реализуются такие проекты? Как мне действовать и в какую сторону копать? Как мне раз в день парсить страницы с ценами и актуализировать базу? Мне нужно написать приложение на сервере, которое грубо говоря висит в треи и запускается раз в день и парсит сайты?

Comment: То что ты хочешь написать, кажется, называется Webcrawler. Погугли на эту тему.

Comment: Вот по быстрому нашел пример на питоне: http://pi-code.blogspot.de/2008/12/1.html

Comment: А вот готовые роботы написанные на яве: http://www.roseindia.net/opensource/webcrawlers.php

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Агрегатор (в вашем случае - агрегатор цен), создается, если у опрашиваемых сайтов есть REST API или RSS.

В случае, когда опрашиваемый сайт не поддерживает указанных технологий, можно сделать следующий трюк:

Найти на сайте страницу с ценами, сохранить ее URL, открыть ее в браузере в режиме разработчика, найти тег, содержащий цену, получить его `id`, если он есть. Иначе, смотрим в браузере цепочку вложенности тегов, ведущую к нужному вам тегу, сохраняем ее (желательно сохранять `id`, или тег вместе с `class`). После подготовительных работ используем класс `HttpClient` для скачивания страницы с ценами, затем парсим ее либой `CsQuery`.

Однако такой подход крайне не универсален: Вам придётся по-разному обрабатывать каждый сайт и обновлять свой код, если структура страницы с ценами изменится.

Comment: Строго говоря, можно парсить страницы и искать по ключевым словам ещё, но с этим и у поисковиков проблемы, ТС точно не потянет.

Comment: Если цены искать по тегам, то при смене цен или добавлении новых услуг, вряд ли придется переписывать признаки поиска

Comment: Нет это я все понимаю, получается у меня на сервере стоит служба , которая парсит со страниц цены и обновляет базу?

Comment: ну конечно не при каждом запросе нужно парсить, а время от времени)

Comment: Разумеется, тут нужна отдельная служба. Еще есть вариант - задание для виндового планировщика.